# Get an alert "Can't download the software because of a network problem" after xcode-select --install

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install xcode on my mac machine (macOS Catalina) and run

```
xcode-select --install
```

but get an alert with message "Can't download the software because of a network problem"

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've found a solution for macOS Catalina *10.15.3* - to install Xcode CommandLineTools manually (actually I need only this part).

**Steps:**

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode
2. Download Command Line Tools for Xcode *11.4.1.* (the latest one)
3. Install this package manually

Comment: This worked for me on OS X 10.15.7! Thanks!

Comment: I had the same error as the OP - on macOS 11.1.  This worked for me too.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Though this is quite an old thread, I would like to mention how I resolved it.
This happens when you set the timezone incorrectly.
Check whether the timezone is correctly set and it will solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, I set the data and time manually but when I changed it to automatically worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It may be that the URL used to download the command line tools is set to a different update server than the Apple default. If so:

`$ sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL`
`https://macpatch.mycompanydomain.com:443/index.sucatalog`

`$ sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL`

`$ xcode-select --install`

`$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL https://macpatch.mycompanydomain.com:443/index.sucatalog`

Comment: this helped a colleague out of a bind after uninstalling Xcode and this got them passed the dreaded "network problem" dialog after trying to brew install git! Thank you! in fact it just started working as soon as he entered `sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL`

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the below command in the mac terminal which will update the Homebrew for Mac os version Mojave 10.14 and update missing packages.

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

[Refer this page for more info](https://dev.to/berry_clione/install-homebrew-on-macos-mojave-4m3m)

If the above method didn't work:

[Download command line manually from here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
After download install the package manually.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToJmi.png)