# Xcode 12.5 with iOS 14.5.1 device getting xcode failed to start remote service com.apple.debugserver on device

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcode-debugger

I have created a new project and running the project on iOS 14.5.1 device with Xcode 12.5. But it is showing an error saying "Xcode failed to start remote service com.apple.debugserver on device"

I have tried all the below options

- Unpaired, paired the device.
- Restarted device.
- Restarted Xcode, Mac system.

**Notes:**

- If I run the app by disabling (Edit Scheme -> Info -> Debug Executable) options then it is working fine, but I can't debug with this option.
- If I run the app in the simulator in debug mode by enabling Debug Executable option then it is working fine.

Attaching a screenshot below for reference.

[image]

Comment: [I have an answer they may help in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378023/1890317)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for this after performing the below steps

1. After installing Xcode12.5 in macOS Big Sur. Check the **CommandLineTools** folder are available in `Developer` folder by executing this command `cd /Library/Developer`. By using `xcode-select --install` command we can install CommandLineTools for the xcode.
2. I am using company provided MacBook Pro. So after executing `xcode-select --install` command, got **network problem** error, this is because installation server configuration is different. By using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233173/get-an-alert-cant-download-the-software-because-of-a-network-problem-after-xc/67222114#67222114) i am able to successfully install the **CommandLineTools**
3. I am using **iOS14.5.1** device. So in this path `Applications -> Xcode(right click and select show packget contents) -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport ->` renamed 14.5 folder name to 14.5.1
4. Now i quit **Xcode**, disconnected **iphone**.
5. Reconnected iPhone with mac. Opened Finder app, here it is asking to **Trust** the iPhone. After clicking on **trust** button i got some error. this error because of `McAfee` software security check. i have disabled that by following steps in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65379635/mac-os-trust-request-error-402-653-181), So as part of this we have to disable `McAfee` by simply executing `sudo /usr/local/McAfee/AntiMalware/VSControl stopoas` command in the terminal.
6. Now i quit **Xcode**, disconnected **iphone**. Reconnected iPhone, opened xcode. Click on trust in prompt in both `Finder -> iphone device name folder`, `iPhone device`
7. After some time it is successfully paired the device. Navigate to `Library -> Developer -> Xcode -> iOS DeviceSupport -> 14.5.1 (18E212) arm64e ->` check **info.plist** file, **symbols** folder available. If these files are avaible then our device is successfully paired with mac system and it is ready for debugging.
8. Now debugging is working fine successfully.